# Extract text from a specific row in the table with Capybara

Tags: capybara

[image]Friends for me to finish my test and I just need to extract the text of the tooltip from the specific line of the table. Thomas Walpole has helped me a lot. Now I can read the excel spreadsheet and I will validate with each line of the application.

```
****** I read excel and get the first line *************
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
  book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/Pasta1.xls', "r")
  sheet = book.worksheet 0
  #sheet.each do |row|
  pp hydrometer = sheet.row(1)

****** reading the specific row of the table *************

I just need to extract this text save in a variable and validate with the hydrometer variable that stores the row of my excel sheet

expect(page).to have_css('tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip="Invisível"]')
```

see the code

```
<tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','bdb','BtnDropDownRow#',1,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','bdb','Select#',1,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowEven tvRoll tvRowSelected" style="cursor:pointer;">
   <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETMATRICOLA_E</td>
   <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Nº Hidrômetro</td>
   <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
   <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
   <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip="[AIMPMATRICOLA]">
      <button onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','bdb','AUTOFILLBTN#',1,'','','','');" class="but butAct" tabindex="0" tooltip="Preenchimento automático ativado" type="BUTTON">
         <div><img src="r/std/icons/checkboxselected64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
      </button>
   </td>
   <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
   <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
      <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','bdb','BtnDropDownRow#',1,'','','','');" class="but">
         <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','bdb','BtnDropDownRow#',2,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','bdb','Select#',2,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
   <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETLETTURA_E</td>
   <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Leitura</td>
   <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
   <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
   <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip=""></td>
   <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
   <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
      <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','bdb','BtnDropDownRow#',2,'','','','');" class="but">
         <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `hydrometer` contains the text you're checking for just interpolate it in the CSS selector you're using

```
expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{hydrometer}']")
```

Since your going through a loop you'd probably also want to interpolate the row number but I don't know what variable you have that in

```
expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_number}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{hydrometer}']")
```

If you really want to get the tooltip text for a specific row you would do

```
text = find("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip]")[:tooltip] # get the tooltip attribute value from the 2nd row
```

but doing that and then comparing it to some other string is bad practice and will lead to flaky tests.  It is much better to do the `have_css` shown above

Comment: How do I get the tooltip text of this line to know if it's coming correctly? Please

Comment: pp expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{@hydrometer}']")

Comment: Reason:, expected `#<Capybara::Session>.has_css?("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='[\"Invisível\"]']")` to be truthy, got false  var @hydrometer = Invisível, . FrontEnd is Invisível.. its same thing!

Comment: @Elis - Read the error message - and the line of code.  The error is telling you that the value of `@hydrometer` was `[\"Invisíve\"]` because that's what is getting interpolated into the CSS.  You need to make sure that @hydrometer has the value you are trying to check for.  In this case it looks like @hydrometer is actaully an array so you'd need to put `@hydrometer[0]` to get the first element, but it's still going to be `Invisível` after that which means you're not setting @hydrometer to what you're looking for

Comment: You don't need to get the tooltip text you just need to make sure the CSS you're building is correct for what you're checking for

Comment: Do no work   ----------------------------------------------, Reason:, expected `#<Capybara::Session>.has_css?("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='${@hidrometro[2]}']")` to be truthy, got false, ----------------------------------------------

Comment: I need to validate if the text of the tooltip corresponds to the item in the list called: N Hydrometer, I will validate the tooltips of each element for example: Reading, Diametro do Hd. etc.

Comment: @Elis. It's impossible for me to tell you exactly how to solve this without the exact information of what all these things are -- you've said that `hydrometer` was the variable, then `@hydrometer`, not you're trying `@hidrometro[2]` as having the value to check.  Your failure above is because you've used `${...}` for the interpolation.  That's javascript format, in Ruby it's `#{...}` to interpolate in a string like you had previously used

Comment: So - `expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{@hidrometro[2]}']")` will look for the element in the 6th column of the 2nd row with the tooltip value equal to the 3rd element in the `@hidrometro` array

Comment: I had already solved the $ issue. I will run it again on Monday because the system is down for the weekend. Thank you for now today I will study to solve my difficulties.

Comment: I don't know if what I'm explaining makes sense, but if this function does the following: the value of @hydrometer = line value of my 'Invisible' worksheet and validate with the Invisible tooltip of the 6th column, in the second line of the element N. Hidrometro so my problem is solved.

Comment: See my new evidence Please.. Great weekend